# "you didn't even start" or "you don't even start", when to use which?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

My sister lost one of my books somewhere in the house a few days ago. Then I asked her to get it back.

I asked her just now about the book. She answered she didn't find it. I guess she didn't even start searching. Should I say

> you didn't even start searching, right?

or

> you don't even start searching, right?

I guess the first one is, if so, when should I use the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking if she has already started something. If she had, that start would already have taken place, so would be in the *past tense*.

Of your two examples, the correct one would be:

> You didn't even start searching, right?

It sounds natural, but I would prefer:

> You *haven't* even *started* searching, right?